# example from elasticsearch documentation

Tags: elasticsearch

I started to study elasticsearch but I just can’t understand one example from documentation :
(This example is taken from here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/query-dsl-intervals-query.html)

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "intervals" : {
      "my_text" : {
        "match" : {
          "query" : "hot porridge",
          "filter" : {
            "script" : {
              "source" : "interval.start > 10 && interval.end < 20 && interval.gaps == 0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What are we trying to find here?
    What interval is ? Is it reserved keyword in painless language or something else. If it is a variable then why do not we explicitly define it (like Int A, Float B)
    What start and stop methods do in this case ?
    I read everything about painless on the elasticsearch site and spent few hours googling this but without luck.
    Can anyone help me ?

Update: Corrected link and provided full example from documentation

Update2: Up

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I can't locate example in link provided, you sure it is proper?

Comment: The link you have included does not have the query you have posted. And your query is incomplete. Please post the entire query or correct link.
Also, I would suggest you to post this in elasticsearch discuss forum

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Just corrected my question.